# File organization - Devise Admin and Admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-organization, file-organization

I'm a pretty new to ROR and i'm in trouble to organize my files.

I'm using Devise and I have two models: Admin and User. Also, I generated the Devise views for the both scopes.

Current I have a folder called admin and my files got a little confused after I created the admins folder.

Current files structure

```
controllers
    ├── admin
    |     ├── dashboard_controller.rb
    |     └── reports_controller.rb
    |
    └── admins
          └── registrations_controller.rb (custom controller inherit from devise controllers)

  views
    ├── admin
    |     ├── dashboard
    |     |      ├───── new.html.erb
    |     |      └───── edit.html.erb
    |     └── reports
    |            ├────── new.html.erb
    |            └────── edit.html.erb
    |
    └── admins
          ├── registrations
          ├── sessions
          └ ...
```

My routes

```
 devise_for :admins, path: 'admin', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}

  authenticate :admin do
    namespace :admin do
      resources   :dashboard,                 only:[:index]
    end
  end
```

In this case, what is the best approach to organize the files? Any materials to recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

I would rename your *admin -> dashboard, reports* into something else. Probably to *dashboard* or *admin_dashboard*. You'll just confuse yourself if you name your Devise model and your controller the same.
:)